# TeamCity Snapshot Dependencies against specific commit

Tags: git, teamcity, snapshot, teamcity-9.0

I have several Team City build configurations which can be simplified to the following:

- A **Test** step which is automatically triggered by various commits and runs tests.
- A **Build** step which should be manually triggered against a known, specific test pass.

Let's say there are 4 commits that automatically trigger the *Test* step:

- *commit_1*: Fails tests
- *commit_2*: Fails tests
- *commit_3*: Passes tests
- *commit_4*: Passes tests

I want to manually trigger the Build step, with a fresh checkout, explicitly tied to *commit_3*.

I have tried setting *Test* as a Snapshot Dependency of *Build*, but this does not give me any option to specify which "run" of the *Test* I want to build against.

With an "artifact dependency" I can choose the specific dependent output to build against. How can I use a Snapshot dependency to choose a specific commit to build against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting test as a Snapshot dependency of Build is correct way of doing this.

After that, when you want to trigger *Build*, press "..." near `Run` button, select "Changes" tab and choose proper commit.

Or, the other way around. Navigate to a *Test* build that you would like to use, use `Actions` -> `Promote` and choos the *Build* build configuration. This will trigger *Build* with same sources revision as current *Test* build.